# Two column list fill div width

Tags: css

I have a two column list in a div, and I want the two columns to fill the entire width of the div.

```
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="list-item">asdfasfd</li>
      <li class="list-item">asdfasfd</li>
      <li class="list-item">asdfasfd</li>
      <li class="list-item">asdfasfd</li>
      <li class="list-item">asdfasfd</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>


.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 450px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul.list {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li.list-item {
  display: inline;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 47%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/h7112hrm/1/

Right now there is 1-2px more spacing in the end. Is there a way to fill the two column green boxes to entire 100% of the outer div? Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Considering the list items are only 47% width and using a 5px margin, I'm not surprised they don't completely fill the containing element

Comment: To the right, inside the div, to the right of the 2nd column green list items. That is why I'm trying to find a way to fill it, because this CSS doesn't seem ideal to me.

Comment: I need spacing between the list items (margins).

Comment: Thank you. What I needed was "calc".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the code, I have modified few things. Dont leave any space between each li. Else use "float:left" instead of "display: inline-block" .

```css
.box {
 border: 1px solid black;
 background-color: gray;
 width: 450px;
}

ul.list {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
  margin:0;
}


li.list-item {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 40px;
 width: calc( 50% - 10px );
 padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="box">
 <ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item">asdfasfd</li><li class="list-item">asdfasfd</li><li class="list-item">asdfasfd</li><li class="list-item">asdfasfd</li><li class="list-item">asdfasfd</li>
 </ul>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What I needed was calc in these situations. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add padding to the left side of the `.box` class, pushing everything over.

```
.box {
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: gray;
width: 450px;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding-left: 4px;<----- added
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Instead of using display use `float:left` this removes the space from `li`. If you are increasing margin then adjust your width accordingly.

```
.box {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: gray;
    width: 450px;
  height:300px;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
  background:#111;
}

.list-item {
    float:left;
  width:49.55%;
  height:100px;
  margin:1px;
  background-color:green;
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```